# I am not able to understand why parent reference variable value of all recursive calls changes as soon as parent=n is done?

Tags: java, object, recursion, reference, pass-by-reference

```
    Node parent;
    private int size;

    public void addNodes() {
        if (size == 0) {
            Node n = new Node(sc.nextInt());
            parent = n;
            root = n;
            size++;
        }

        System.out.println("Does " + parent.data + " have a left node");

        if (sc.nextBoolean()) {
            Node n = new Node(sc.nextInt());
            parent.left = n;
            parent = n;
            addNodes();
        }

        System.out.println("Does " + parent.data + " have a right node?");

        if (sc.nextBoolean()) {
            Node n = new Node(sc.nextInt());
            parent.right = n;
            parent = n;
            addNodes();
        }
    }
```

I cannot understand why the `parent` reference variable value of all recursive calls changes as soon as `parent = n` is done.

If there is any doubt in question, just run the program. I have tried to create a binary tree and initialize it using recursion.

Comment: Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291846/14790684).

Comment: *the `parent` reference variable value of all recursive calls*... there's only one value because it's a field, not a variable. *If there is any doubt in question, just run the program.* You haven't posted a program, just a snippet of code.